# python 2.7 RegEx - problems with search

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

i'm using the search module but it doesn't work right.
when there is one thing that suits what i'm looking for its work good. like:

```
text = 'lets GET /keyser/22300/ HTTP/1.1 goodbeleive'

match = re.search('GET (.*) HTTP/1.1',text)
match.group(1)
```

ofcourse i did import re and everything. and i get what i want - the text between GET and HTTP.
but when there are some of this pattern its suppossed to take the first one who suitable.. but its takes everything after the HTTP...

```
text = 'lets GET /keyser/22300/ HTTP/1.1 goodbeleive GET /cyberbit/288/ 
HTTP/1.1therebetter u'

match = re.search('GET (.*) HTTP/1.1',text)
match.group(1)
```

i get this answer:

```
'/keyser/22300/ HTTP/1.1 good now beleive GET /cyberbit/288/'
```

on my program i wanna do a findall to extract all the pattern like this but ofcourse it does not work

please help me
if you can give also example to a good-working findall
thank you!

Comment: by the way i notice now how to make it more clear for you guys. its take a GET and HTTP as wanted. but the largest one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the pattern lazy, by adding a `?`.

```
>>> re.findall(r'GET (.*?) HTTP/1.1', text)
['/keyser/22300/', '/cyberbit/288/']
```